# Взаимодействие UWP приложения с приложением Win32

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

у меня есть необходимость реализовать обмен данными между приложением UWP и приложением на .NET 4.5.2. Причем сделать это необходимо на одной машине. На основе сокетов, вебсокетов, пайп-каналов и других вариантов межпроцессного, на сколько я понял, сделать нельзя из-за ограничений UWP. 
Единственное, что нашел - это поместить проект с .NET приложением в один пакет с UWP и уже внутри пакета обмениваться данными. К сожалению в данный момент это почти невозможно, так как для этого придется глобально переписывать старое не UWP приложение.
В связи с чем вопрос, есть ли еще какие-нибудь возможности для обмена данными?

Comment: Поднимите локальный вэб из приложения и обращайтесь к нему из UWP. WCF сервис например. Ещё вариант завести службу в Виндовз.. :) что будет стоить не малых хлопот..

Comment: @NewView Только вот чтобы провернуть это, нужно сначала снять ограничение на локальные соединения. Это в принципе не проблема сделать скриптом, но тогда возникает вопрос - в чем вообще смысл использования UWP в данной схеме? Единственное преимущество UWP - простота развертывания через магазин и предсказуемая безопасность. Никому не нужно UWP-приложение, для установки которого нужно запускать какой-то скрипт с правами администратора.

Comment: Но мое кромольное мнение, что место сетевых нагруженных сервисов и серверов на *nix платформах. Для этого там есть все условия, включая такие фронт енды как nginx. Но ограничения есть и там, справедливости ради, для обхождения это проблемы надо строить кластеры.

Comment: UWP в моем случае нужно чтобы запустить пакет, содержащий winmd файл и библиотеку. Поэтому приходится придумывать огород.